# Sparql query bad formed

Tags: python, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I'm trying to build a sparql query based on a list of properties but I get an error saying that the query is bad formed. The problem is I don't know what to do to fix it.

This is the function:

```
def create_query(dbpedia_uri, props):
    #props are something like this ('dbpedia-owl', 'birthdate')
    filters = ''

    for prop in QUERIES_DICT[ename]:
        filters += ' OPTIONAL { ?x %s:%s ?%s. } \n' % (corresp_dict[prop[0]], prop[1], prop[1])

    query = u"""
        SELECT * WHERE {
.          <%s>.
          ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
          %s
          FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
        }
    """ % (dbpedia_uri, filters)

    return query
```

This is the query I get:

```
u"\n        SELECT * WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tim_Cook>\n          ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.\n          OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate. }\n OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthPlace. }\n OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:name ?name. }\n OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:profession ?profession. }\n OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:residence ?residence. }\n OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:website ?website. }\n \n          FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')\n        }\n    "
```

Or printed:

```
        SELECT * WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tim_Cook>
          ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
          OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate. }
 OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthPlace. }
 OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:name ?name. }
 OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:profession ?profession. }
 OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:residence ?residence. }
 OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:website ?website. }

          FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
        }
```

Comment: [AndyS's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18279160/1281433) is spot on;  the problem is that the prefixes aren't defined.  Can you include the text of the "error saying that the query is bad formed"?  I expect that it includes a similar message.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define all the prefixes used e.g. dbpprop ,dbpedia-owl

Try: http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html

Comment: The prefixes are defined, look below on the generated query and you'll see them added.

Comment: @Rod0n The generated query as shown does not include any lines such as `PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>`.  It doesn't define the prefixes.  The SPARQL validator that @AndyS linked to makes this clear, saying "Line 2, column 14: Unresolved prefixed name: dbpedia-owl:abstract".  Without defining the prefix, `dbpedia-owl:abstract` can't be expanded into a full IRI.